# Partitioning Data in SQL On-Demand with Blob Storage as Data Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift, azure-synapse, amazon-redshift-spectrum

In Amazon Redshift there is a way to create a partition key when using your S3 bucket as a data source. [Link.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html#c-spectrum-external-tables-partitioning)

I am attempting to do something similar in Azure Synapse using the SQL On-Demand service.

Currently I have a storage account that is partitioned such that it follows this scheme:

```
-Sales (folder)
  - 2020-10-01 (folder)
    - File 1
    - File 2
  - 2020-10-02 (folder)
    - File 3
    - File 4
```

To create a view and pull in all 4 files I ran the command:

```sql
CREATE VIEW testview3 AS SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ( BULK 'Sales/*/*.csv', FORMAT = 'CSV', PARSER_VERSION = '2.0', DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', FIRSTROW = 2 ) AS tv1;
```

If I run a query of `SELECT * FROM [myview]` I receive data from all 4 files.

How can I go about creating a partition key so that I could run a query such as

```sql
SELECT * FROM [myview] WHERE folderdate > 2020-10-01
```

so that I can only analyze data from Files 3 and 4?

I know I can edit my OPENROWSET BULK statement but I want to be able to get all the data from my container at first and then constrain searches as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless SQL can parse partitioned folder structure's using the filename (where you wish to load a specific file or files) and filepath (where you wish to load all files in this said path). More information on syntax and usage is available on documentation online.

In your case, you can parse all files from '2020-10-01' and beyond using the filepath syntax such as filepath(1) > '2020-10-01'

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to figure this out with what you had suggested.

Comment: Thought I may as well ask this here, is it possible to create an internal table within a SQL On-Demand instance? If not is there a way to union a normal SQL DB table/view with a SQL On-Demand table/view? In a way I would be looking to have some data on an internal table and while having most in blob storage that I could query off SQL On-Demand as needed.

Comment: You can use linked server on managed instance or external table with type=RDBMS (this is in preview) to connect form SQL MI/SQL DB to Synapse on-demand and join sql be table with remote synapse table.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from Raunak I ended up with the following syntax for my query.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS testview6
GO

CREATE VIEW testview6 AS
SELECT *,
    r.filepath(1) AS [date]
FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'Sales/*/*.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV', PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        FIRSTROW = 2
        ) AS [r]
WHERE r.filepath(1) IN ('2020-10-02');
```

You can adjust the granularity of your partitioning by the addition of extra wildcards (*) and r.filepath(x) statements.

For instance you can create your query such as:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS testview6
GO

CREATE VIEW testview6 AS
SELECT *,
    r.filepath(1) AS [year],
    r.filepath(2) as [month]
FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'Sales/*-*-01/*.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV', PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureBlob',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        FIRSTROW = 2
        ) AS [r]
WHERE r.filepath(1) IN ('2020')
AND r.filepath(2) IN ('10');
```