# Partitioning Data on BULK INSERT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

In a previous post I was able to successfully use filepath metadata from an OPENROWSET command in SQL On-Demand to create a partitioning scheme within a view. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745782/partitioning-data-in-sql-on-demand-with-blob-storage-as-data-source).

I am looking to replicate this in a normal Azure SQL Database view. When I try to run the same command I get an error stating

> Cannot find either column "r" or the user-defined function or aggregate "r.filepath", or the name is ambiguous.

This is what I am running in SSMS for my Azure SQL database instance.

```
CREATE VIEW testview6 AS
SELECT *, r.filepath(1) as [date]
FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'Sales/2020-10-01/Iris_Shortened.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'azure_blob_sas5',
        SINGLE_CLOB
        ) AS [r];
```

I am not sure of what I am doing wrong. My goal is to create a partitioning scheme so that filepath metadata can be used for parsing what is needed. Is this something that is only available with SQL On-Demand?

Answer (score 0):

Currently yes.
This is a great idea, can you create a feature request for Azure SQL database [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database)?